# Using @Document and @Entity at the same time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, nosql

I tried to use @Document with @Entity on the same Entity class but I get the following error when I implement both repositories (ElasticSearchRepository and CrudRepository) 
`The bean 'esRepo', defined in null, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it has to do with Spring Data JPA component scanner, try adding the following configuration classes and put both repositories in different packages
 for Elasticsearch repos: 
`@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "org.ala.springdataes.esrepository")
public class ESConfig {
}`

for JPA repos: 

`@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.ala.springdataes.repository")
public class RepoConfiguration {
}`

Comment: Thanks  I was trying to use same Entity for Postgres and Google Firestore, This solution worked in my case. Domain object has two @Entity annotation each coming from respective packages