# Using @Document notation in an @Entity

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have entities marked with the `@Entity` notation for jpa, such as

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "category", schema = "\"public\"")
public class Category extends AbstractBaseEntity {
...
```

But I also want to use elastic search repository and for such I need to use the `@Document` notation, however, if I use both I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'elasticsearchRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryElasticSearchRepository' defined in br.com.gwcloud.smartplace.catalog.elasticsearch.repositories.CategoryElasticSearchRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on ElasticSearchConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: 5,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: 5,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]
```

My configuration file is as following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories("br.com.gwcloud.smartplace.catalog.elasticsearch.repositories")
    public class ElasticSearchConfig {    
        @Bean
        public RestHighLevelClient client() {
            ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration 
                = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                    .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
                    .build();
    
            return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
        }    
        @Bean
        public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
            return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client());
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/54987837/14474468

Comment: Thank you but this does not solve my problem as I already have repositories separated in different packages.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message it's pretty obvious what the problem is:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

When you put `@Document` on your entity, Spring Data Elasticsearch tries to initialize the repository and tries to connect to the Elasticsearch cluster.

Either your configuration is wrong or not existent, in the latter case Spring Data Elasticsearch tries to connect to a local instance running at `localhost:9200`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I do have a configuration file, I put it in the description should the problem be related to it.

Comment: and do you have an Elasticsearch running on your machine?

Comment: I did not actually, but now It's running and the error continues.

Comment: can you access Elasticsearch with `curl`? `curl http://localhost:9200`

Comment: and how do you start your application?

Comment: Yes I can access it, and I start the application with maven.

Comment: that's strange; can you provide a minimal project to reproduce this?